# Open Application Y from push notification created from Application X

Tags: java, android, push-notification, push

Say Application X has push notification service. On push receive, the intent is to receive the JSON in PushListenerService and add a date and time to Google Calendar (the code to do this is below for reference). However, if Application X is closed, yet still receiving push notification, how does one open Google Calendar?

Opening the push notification only starts the app, not Google Calendar. I cannot start Google Calendar from a service, and a broadcast receiver in the main thread with below code does not open Google Calendar.

```
           Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    beginTime.set(NPdateStartYearInt, NPdateStartMonthInt - 1, NPdateStartDayInt,
                            NPdateStartHourInt, NPdateStartMinuteInt);
                    Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    endTime.set(NPdateFinishYearInt, NPdateFinishMonthInt - 1, NPdateFinishDayInt,
                            NPdateFinishHourInt, NPdateFinishMinuteInt);
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                            .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                            .putExtra(Events.TITLE, title)
                            .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, text)
                            .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
                            .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
                            .putExtra(Events.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.GREEN)
                            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, R.string.emailAddress);
```

Comment: whenever you receive the push notification the specified activity get opended,
inside activity on create whenever you will receive the Nofitication in Bundle, 
then based on bundle value you can perform specific task.

Comment: This doesn't help. If the app is closed and the push is received, the push opens said app on a new onCreate(). This is equivalent to the user just starting the app